# Is it possible to make commercial (or not) IC´s with FPGA?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am working as TV repairer but some "IC jungles for TV's" are from China without almost information and often they are impossible to find.

My question is : Is it possible to do a IC jungle for TV, LCD, plasma, etc by aplying FPGA.

I know by microcontroller I can't do it because they are not so flexibles as FPGA's.

For example look this IC is from a TV and it's impossible to find out because is from China:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrcnh.jpg]

And this is the diagram:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oThq4.png]

Is it possible to do most IC's impossible to find (because they are from china mostly) by FPGA?

Comment: Is your question the simple "Can it be done?" - The answer is of course "yes". Anything is possible if you have enough money or time. Or is your question about finding information or  the process of designing a FPGA to replace an IC chip? This question is much to broad.

Comment: Minor style thing: countries are always with capital letters in English.